# Make below design without pre tag

Tags: html, css

In `<pre>` is easy to make that figure but i want to make this pattern via `<div>`

Is possible ? With margin ?

I try with margin and its successfully done but some pattern cant make via this techniques.

Successfully Done :-

```
*********
**** ****
***   ***
**     **
*       *
*       *
**     **
***   ***
**** ****
*********
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="pattern">
    <div class="space">
        *********<br>
        ****<span style="margin-left: 11%;"></span>****<br>
        ***<span style="margin-left: 33%;"></span>***<br>
        **<span style="margin-left: 55%;"></span>**<br>
        *<span style="margin-left: 77%;"></span>*<br>
        *<span style="margin-left: 77%;"></span>*<br>
        **<span style="margin-left: 55%;"></span>**<br>
        ***<span style="margin-left: 33%;"></span>***<br>
        ****<span style="margin-left: 11%;"></span>****<br>
        *********
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.pattern {
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    display: flex;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 100%;
}
```

Want to Implement

```
    *
   * *
  *   *
 *     *
*       *
 *     *
  *   *
   * *
    *
```

**Snippet**

```css
.pattern {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="pattern">
  <div class="space">
    *********<br>
    ****<span style="margin-left: 11%;"></span>****<br>
    ***<span style="margin-left: 33%;"></span>***<br>
    **<span style="margin-left: 55%;"></span>**<br>
    *<span style="margin-left: 77%;"></span>*<br>
    *<span style="margin-left: 77%;"></span>*<br>
    **<span style="margin-left: 55%;"></span>**<br>
    ***<span style="margin-left: 33%;"></span>***<br>
    ****<span style="margin-left: 11%;"></span>****<br>
    *********
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: well, i saw people asking about some complex shape, etc ... but why doing this with HTML/CSS ? any particular reason ?

Comment: Because We Want to Upload In Our Blog / Website and for beginners Html and css is one of the best and easiest choice so ....

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. Without any CSS, there is this... https://jsfiddle.net/9ge0cLLL/ (Don't tell anyone I told you.)

Comment: Thanks, You Made With Table And Its Too Big , I Already Make It By Margin Show Above , I Need ( Waiting For Code ) Pattern , Give Me ( Without <pre> ) That , If you Have time !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I added my own answer.

```css
.child{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-weight: 700;
}
p:nth-child(1),p:nth-child(9) {
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}
p:nth-child(2),p:nth-child(8) {
  letter-spacing: 25px;
  margin-right: -25px;
}
p:nth-child(3),p:nth-child(7) {
  letter-spacing: 50px;
  margin-right: -50px;
}
p:nth-child(4),p:nth-child(6) {
  letter-spacing: 70px;
  margin-right: -70px;
}
p:nth-child(5) {
  letter-spacing: 100px;
  margin-right: -100px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="child">
  <p>*</p>
  <p>**</p>
  <p>**</p>
  <p>**</p>
  <p>**</p>
  <p>**</p>
  <p>**</p>
  <p>**</p>
  <p>*</p>
</div>
```